# How do I fix these armatures?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

So, I'm trying to figure out how to rig a model for animation, and I've come across a problem. [image]

Right now, I'm working on the leg bones, and I want both of the legs to be part of the bottom torso, the top torso to be connected to the bottom, and the head and arms to be connected to the top torso. However, I keep finding that when I add "Automatic Weights", it only allows one of the legs to be fused to the bottom torso. The other just stays disconnected.

Does anybody know how to fix this, and how I can prevent this for future models?

Answer (score 0):

for what i am seeing in the wireframe pic, your box model is disconnected from every box model you made, so automatic weights isnt gonna work properly if your models are splited or separated individually like this, but then parent every model to the respective bone, instead with bone parent option in the menu when doing re-parenting...